# Nuxt v3 with nuxt-content: how to render math equations in markdown?

Tags: nuxtjs3, katex, nuxt-content

I have a new nuxt-content site using Nuxt (nuxt@3.0.0 and @nuxt/content@2.3.0) and would like to render math equations from my markdown files using the usual `$...$` syntax. What do I need to add to get katex (or any) math rendering?

Answer (score -1):

One easy solution might be using MDC(Markdown Component) In this way you can render any Vue component in markdown. Create a general MathRender.Vue component then passes all data from md file and renders as you wish in your Vue file.

[Doc Link](https://content.nuxtjs.org/guide/writing/mdc)

example.md file

```
::card
The content of the card
::
```

Card.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="p-6 border bg-white dark:bg-black dark:border-gray-700 rounded">
    <slot />
  </div>
</template>
```